read properties of undefined (reading 'map') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') at Dialogs
Всем привет! Я новичок и не могу понять как это пофиксить  read properties of undefined (reading 'map') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') at Dialogs
const Dialogs = (props) => {

 let dialogsElements = props.dialogs.map((d) => (
    <DialogItem name={d.name} id={d.id} 
  )); 
  
  let messagesElements = props.messages.map((m) => (
    <Message message={m.message} 
  ));

App: Dialogs
store={props.store}
dialogs={props.dialogs} 
messages={props.messages}
newMessageBody={props.newMessageBody}


У вас неверно передаётся props.dialogs

Этот вопрос похож на: Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or null (reading ***). Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

У вас props.dialogs - это underfind. Значит у props нет ключа dialogs или значение по этому ключу задано некорректно

а как добавить этот ключ в пропс?

при добавлении компонента на страницу

Например: <Dialogs store = {переменная} dialogs={переменная} и т. д./>
